# Server side display for Wordpress, Joomla and Drupal sites

Tags: wordpress, hosting, web-hosting, website

The CMS based websites on my web server, with several virtual servers, are all showing php script in the index.php file, see the screenshot.
I am using apache 2.4.7 and the system information is as bellow.

*System hostname servername (xx.xx.xx.xx)

Operating system    Ubuntu Linux 14.04.3

Webmin version  1.760
Time on system  Fri Jan 13 15:07:34 2017

Kernel and CPU  Linux 3.19.0-25-generic on x86_64

Processor information   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5650 @ 2.67GHz, 24 cores

System uptime   45 days, 3 hours, 31 minutes

Running processes   328

CPU load averages   0.00 (1 min) 0.03 (5 mins) 0.05 (15 mins)

CPU usage   0% user, 0% kernel, 0% IO, 100% idle

Real memory 2.46 GB used, 62.91 GB total*

Virtual memory  0 bytes used, 63.99 GB total

Local disk space    86.42 GB used, 853.28 GB total

It's my first time posting a question on serverfault.com, and I am a beginner as a system administrator any mistakes made, please be kind.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3welt.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have PHP installed, either as part of those packages or with something like

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

then on Ubuntu you also need `libapache2-mod-php` installed. Check for it:

```
sudo apt-cache policy libapache2-mod-php
```

Comment: thanks, that helped and some configurations to apache config file.